# What is this technique called in css?

Tags: html, css, image

Default image:

[image: 1]

After uploading via using `dropzone.js`, hovering it:

[image: 2]

When I create a custom image with css `opacity: 0.5`:

[image: 3]

It looks different from the second image. How to make image effecting like the second image via using css (not including text)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for CSS Filters, specifically Blur.

```
filter: blur(5px);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: Aw, you ninja'd me!

Comment: Sorry! I'll send you some positive SO karma.

Comment: Perfect. Can I buy you a beer?

Comment: I appreciate it, but there is no need to do that. Just pay it forward and share your new knowledge!